# using f:ajax get javax.el.PropertyNotFoundExceptionTarget Unreachable, identifier 'TestBean' resolved to null

Tags: ajax, jsf, exception, javabeans

added f:ajax tag to my jsf page, with the hopes of using ajax

```
<td class="row-center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" >
<h:commandButton value="run test" action="#{TestBean.runTest1}">
    <f:ajax render="output" />
</h:commandButton>
</td>
```

my bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

public void runTest1() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException, InterruptedException {


}
```

had been working before added f:ajax tag

any ideas what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

following error message:

An Error Occurred:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @102,119 action="#{TestBean.runTest1}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'TestBean' resolved to null
+- Stack Trace
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @102,119 action="#{TestBean.runTest1}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'TestBean' resolved to null
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:791)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1256)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:181)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:641)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:600)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1703)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @102,119 action="#{TestBean.runTest1}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'TestBean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: the default name for the ManagedBean starts with a lower-case, try `#{testBean.runTest1}`

Comment: Bingo!!  changed #{TestBean.runTest1} to #{testBean.runTest1} and now it seems to be finding the Bean but now get new error: /index.xhtml @106,119 value="#{testBean.runTest1Result}": Property 'runTest1Result' not found on type com.vigilance.jsf.TestBean
will edit above to reflect new problem

Comment: This "typo" problem is impossibly caused by just adding `<f:ajax>` as you initially implied in the question. You should have tested it more carefully before dumping it into a question. I.e. does the problem *really* disappear when you remove `<f:ajax>`, exactly as you're implying?

Comment: I didn't have the error before adding the f:ajax tag.  I have the error after adding the f:ajax tag.  I have a different error after changing the case of the Bean call in the jsf.

Comment: Why are you chameleonizing an existing question for a completely different question? It's now practically incomprehensible. Press `Ask Question` button if you have a new question.

Comment: Ok I see.  I thought it would be more efficient to modify the existing question rather than create a completely new question.

Comment: But the new problem with the Property not found error has also been solved now.  I made runTest1Result private and removed the static modifiers from the getter and setter

Comment: That's correct. You were just not adhering the Javabeans specification at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property not found error resolved by making property private and removing static modifiers from parameter getter and setters:

```
    private static String runTest1Result;  

public String getRunTest1Result() {
    return runTest1Result;
}

public void setRunTest1Result(String runTest1Result) {
    TestBean.runTest1Result = runTest1Result;
}
```

Initial javax.el.PropertyNotFoundExceptionTarget Unreachable 'TestBean' resolved by changing case of first letter of Bean call from #{TestBean.runTest1} to #{testBean.runTest1}